# Using emacs to edit HTML5 documents

Tags: html, svn, emacs, repository

Using this link here to set up my emacs for html5 : [here](https://github.com/hober/html5-el).

In the how to section there is a step:

> First, you'll need to fetch the RELAX NG schema from the WHAT Task
>   Force subversion repository; a simple make relaxng in this directory
>   should do the trick.

How is this accomplished in ubuntu14.04 and Windows 7?

Could someone please tell me how to fetch RELAX NG from the said repos in svn. The tutorial seems to contain nothing about it.

Comment: Were you able to get this working using the `svn` command in the answer I submitted?

Answer (score 1):

> First, you'll need to fetch the RELAX NG schema from the WHAT Task Force subversion repository; a simple make relaxng in this directory should do the trick.

This means that you should run `make relaxng`. On Ubuntu this will probably work out of the box. If not, make sure you've got the `make` and `subversion` packages installed.

On Windows you probably don't have `make`, though it sounds like you've got Subversion. Looking at the `relaxng` target in the `Makefile` we can see the command that should be run from the repository root:

```
svn co http://whattf.svn.cvsdude.com/syntax/trunk/relaxng/ relaxng
```

Comment: It should be mentioned, that make is to be done in the html5-el dir, not the one fetched from svn